# Flash as3: Load external swf to main stage from button inside a movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie clip on my main stage. There are 2 buttons. I need the 2 buttons to load an external swf, place it on the main stage and have it centered there.

I can get the script to load them in the current movie clip but I need them to be placed on the main stage.

```
var loader_mc:Loader = new  Loader();
addChild(loader_mc);

buttoninsidemc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  buttonClick)

function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    try {
        loader_mc.unloadAndStop();
    } catch(e:Error) {

    }

    var urlRequest : URLRequest = new  URLRequest("externalswf1.swf");
    loader_mc.load(urlRequest);
}


buttoninsidemc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  buttonClick2)

function  buttonClick2(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    try {
        loader_mc.unloadAndStop();
    } catch(e:Error) {

    }

    var urlRequest : URLRequest = new  URLRequest("externalswf2.swf");
    loader_mc.load(urlRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code that will add loaded swf to the stage:

```
function buttonClick2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("externalswf2.swf"));
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    var movie:* = LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget).content;
    //Adding content to the stage
    stage.addChild(movie);
}
```

Or you can change only one line of code in your realisation:

```
   stage.addChild(loader_mc);
```

Comment: I just tried the code and received no errors. However The globe is not showing up at all. Here is some more information in case any misunderstanding. the movie clip has an instance name of "mc1". inside the movie clip i have 2 buttons, they have instance names of "button1" and "button2". I want those buttons to load "externalclip.swf" and bring it to the front and unload the original. Thanks so much for the help. sorry it took so long. been a very busy week.