# Load Another SWF File after Video in SWF File Ends

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two SWF files. First o is `intro.swf` and the second one is `menu.swf`.

`intro.swf` only contains an external video that will play automatically. The video ends in 45 seconds. I want `menu.swf` loaded automatically after the video in `intro.swf` ends.

The only code I know and work is in this page: 
[Flash as3: Load external swf to main stage from button inside a movie clip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336242/flash-as3-load-external-swf-to-main-stage-from-button-inside-a-movie-clip). But it only work for a button.

I don't want user to click button to go to another SWF file. I want it to be loaded automatically.

Here is the folder link of the SWF files: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/l4wd4hbwyame9/demo

Can someone help me? I'm new to ActionScript. Please go easy on me.

Comment: Are you in control of the intro.swf?  eg. do you have the source files and can modify it?

Comment: There isn't an easy "Do this" generic kind of answer.  Everything depends on how the intro.swf is build and the security context it's loaded with into your main app.  Post the swf if you can, or the source code for it.

Comment: Yes. I have the source files and can modify it. There is no code inside I add the `intro.swf`. I actually add video with help from this page : https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/add-video-flash.html

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I already provide the SWF in the post. There is no code inside the SWF files though.

Comment: You can use dispatchEvent. It triggers a listener and then you can automate whatever you want.

Comment: @AinaAiikyo I think that you are using a FLVPlayback component, to play your video, on which you can add an `Event.COMPLETE` event listener to detect the end of the video and then load the second SWF ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my method to add the video. Now, the is added by code. This is the code that works for me with help from fellow commentators.

```
import fl.video.*;
var player:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
addChild(player);

player.source = "video.mp4";
player.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete );
player.setSize(1280, 720);



function onLoaderComplete( e:Event ):void {
    trace( "first swf loaded" );
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("menu.swf"));

}


function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    var movie:* = LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget).content;
    //Adding content to the stage
    stage.addChild(movie);
}
```